# Count number of occurances of an element in a list

Tags: smlnj

I have the following function:

```
getcountof(x,l::ls) = 
if x=l then  (1 + getcountof(x,ls))
else getcountof(x,ls)
|getcountof(x,[]) = 0;
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong in it?
I get the error:

```
stdIn:1.2-1.17 Error: syntax error: deleting  ELSE ID
stdIn:1.22-20.12 Error: syntax error: deleting  RPAREN BAR ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You've missed the `fun` keyword from the start of your definition!

Try this instead:

```
fun getcountof(x,l::ls) = 
     if x=l then  (1 + getcountof(x,ls))
     else getcountof(x,ls)
  | getcountof(x,[]) = 0;
```

This is a trap for people familiar with Haskell.